# ffmpeg: Capture x11grab video with automatic 10mins splitting

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-capture, video-processing, screen-capture

I'm aware I can split the ffmpeg captured video in a second step, with ffmpeg, however would be nice to be able to do it in 1 step.

The command [I use](https://github.com/elgalu/docker-selenium/blob/55666165b87cb3027ccc755a386f515879046233/video-rec/bin/ffmpeg-start-sh#L18) to capture is

```
ffmpeg -an -y -f x11grab \
  -framerate ${FFMPEG_FRAME_RATE} \
  -video_size ${FFMPEG_FRAME_SIZE} ${FFMPEG_CODEC_ARGS} \
  -i "${DISPLAY}.0+0,0" \
  "${VIDEO_PATH}"
```

Which option can I add to that capture cmd to tell it to automatically split the file in 10mins chunks or 5mb chunks for example?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [stream segmenter](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#segment_002c-stream_005fsegment_002c-ssegment) to set a segment time limit. 
Example for 10 second segments each starting with a near-zero timestamp:

```
ffmpeg -f x11grab [..] -f segment -segment_time 10 -reset_timestamps 1 out%03d.mp4
```

Splitting may not be accurate unless you force key-frames at the split-points.